# Not able to map the url in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have request url like http://localhost:8080/api/create/ ,and the controller has the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getApiResponse(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws Exception {}
```

How will the control comes to this method ? I thers any way in spring to do this as i want the request Mapping url to be '/' only

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 0):

The point of the request-mapping is to map each method to a different url. In your case:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/create")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web application is a default web application on your application server, i.e. you do no have to mention the path to application itself in your URL you have to say

`@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
or

`@RequestMapping(value = "/api/create/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

or put `@RequestMapping` annotation on class:
`@RequestMapping(value = "/api/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
and then mark `getApiResponse` method with annotation
`@RequestMapping(value = "/create/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

You can also mention several URLs into one `@RequestMapping` annotation:

`@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/", "/api", "/api/*", "/api/create/"})`

Comment: thanks for the idea,the requirement is like ther equest url can be anything http://localhost:8080/api/create?test="" or http://localhost:8080/api/create/edit but ther equestMapping should be just '/'